# How to pass array from view to controller's action cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm fitering orders on basis of date, and I want to export the filtered orders, How to pass array from view to controller's action cakephp?

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Export Filtered Orders', 
     array('action' => 'export_filtered', 'orders' => $orders),
     array('class' => 'btn btn-success')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't do that because it's against the MVC pattern and it won't work any way because this happens client side, you'll have to do a new request.

Alternativly use AJAX to update your view or implement the PRG pattern to refresh the page and apply the filters, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get